# Wasserstein compactness of sublevel sets of relative entropy

Tags: it.information-theory, calculus-of-variations, optimal-transportation

Let $\mathcal{P}({\mathbb{R}^d})$ denote the set of Borel probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$, and let $\pi \in \mathcal{P} (\mathbb{R}^d)$. It is known that the sets $\{ \mu \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^d) :\, KL( \mu \mid \pi ) \leq C\}$ are compact with respect to the weak convergence of probability measures, as well as w.r.t. setwise convergence. What about with respect to the 2-Wasserstein metric? (If one replaces $\mathcal{P}({\mathbb{R}^d})$ with $\mathcal{P}_2({\mathbb{R}^d})$.)

Comment: What do you mean, $\pi\in \mathbb R^d$? Is $\pi$ a probability measure, or just a (posisbly unbounded, e.g. Lebesgue) nonnegative measure?

Comment: Perhaps a relevant comment is that the $W_2$ distance is well-known to metrize "weak convergence + convergence of the 2nd moments"?

Comment: Sorry, fixed typo regarding $\pi$. As for your second comment, I agree this is surely relevant, but do you have an idea of how to use this to resolve the issue?

Comment: Well, this means that the only issue is a posisble escape of mass at infinity.

Comment: Agreed. Do you have a proof that this is a non-issue, or know of a counter-example?

Comment: Neither. What can you tell us about the refernce measure $\pi$? By any chance,  is it $\lambda$ log-concave for some $\lambda>0$?

Comment: I think it is fine to assume that $\pi$ itself has finite second moment, but $\lambda$-log-concavity would be overly restrictive.